# HPQC ALM : what is the format for Date field in REST based query

Tags: alm

I am trying to use REST call to HP QC ALM12. It works so far but hit a problem when trying to query based on a Date field. Wondering what's the correct syntax to specify a Date query. For example, for the field 'creation-time', how do I filter result within a period ? I have tried these but got HTTP 500 error:

{creation-time[>= '2015-01-01' AND <= '2015-06-01']}
{creation-time[>= '2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z']

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

figured out the correct syntax, it is:

```
field_name[>=yyyy-MM-dd AND <=yyyy-MM-dd]
```

not quoted.